# unable to open dependencies file Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode10, swift4.2

Upon upgrading my code to Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2 I can't build with my  custom Objective C classes.

This is a sample error:

```
error: unable to open dependencies file (/Users/James/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/INDX-czfaxcphlmzffxehpjcbkopvgczo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/INDX01.build/Release-iphonesimulator/INDX01.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MoreTableViewDataSource.d)Command CompileC emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Yes I deleted the derived data folder, cleaned, podded, etc, over and over again and check some flags for good measure.

Nothing changed just the upgrade. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Gave up. Converted those Objective C classes into swift. It compiles and  runs now. Maybe Apple is being aggressive to weed out Objective C  ?